# Connecting Skype for Business with ChatBot

Tags: powershell, botframework, chatbot, skype-for-business, skype-bots

I am trying to deploy Bot on skype and facing this error,
Could anyone please suggest the solution for the same:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $TenentAdminDomainId = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input your domain id in <user>@<domain>.com'
Input your domain id in <user>@<domain>.com: test2@botwork.onmicrosoft.com
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> New-CsOnlineApplicationEndpoint -ApplicationId fc1d28c4-7ff2-41dd-9a1b-a5652949d051 -Name TestBotAP -Uri sip:$TenentAdminDomainId
Cmdlet invocation error
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-CsOnlineApplicationEndpoint], CmdletInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Error processing cmdlet request,Microsoft.Rtc.Management.Hosted.PlatformService.NewPlatformServiceAppEndpointConfigCmdlet
    + PSComputerName        : adminin1.online.lync.com

Could not find the application endpoint
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Microsoft.Rtc.M...cation endpoint:PlatformServiceCmdletException) [New-CsOnlineApplicationEndpoint], PlatformServiceException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Could not get application endpoint or the Uri is already present as an User in BVD,Microsoft.Rtc.Management.Hosted.PlatformService.NewPlatformServiceAppEndpointConfigCmdlet
    + PSComputerName        : adminin1.online.lync.com
```

Answer (score 0):

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/skype-for-business-bot-framework/docs/bot-common-errors

> FullyQualifiedErrorId : Could not get application endpoint or the Uri
>   is already present as a User in BVD
>
> Delete the existing user account with the same sipuri in tenant, or
>   run the cmdlet using a sipuri that does not already exist in the
>   tenant.